# angular controller structure variations

Tags: angularjs, controller

I've been gifted with a project from a previous dev, and he's been building in a style I'm not familiar with.

1. The entire thing is wrapped in an anonymous function and
   immediately executed.
2. The controllers are first declared and injected, then called as
   functions.
3. All controllers are in the same file.

**cartController.js:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('App')

        .controller('cartController', cartController)
        .controller('masterCartonModalInstanceController', masterCartonModalInstanceController)
        .controller('summaryModalInstanceController', summaryModalInstanceController)
        // more controllers ...

    cartController.$inject = ['$http', '$stateParams', '$location', '$uibModal', '$log', 'toastr', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', 'Cart', 'CartObservable'];

    function cartController($http, $stateParams, $location, $uibModal, $log, toastr, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, Cart, CartObservable) {
       var vm = this;
       ...
    }

    masterCartonModalInstanceController.$inject = ['$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance', 'cart'];

    function masterCartonModalInstanceController($uibModal, $uibModalInstance, cart) {
       var vm = this;
       ...
    }
})();
```

This is what I'm familiar with:

**app.js**

```
var portalApp = angular.module("portalApp");
```

**editController.js**

```
var portalApp = angular.module("portalApp");

portalApp.controller('editController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
    'use strict';

    var vm = this;
```

My questions are:

1. Is this guy doing this a valid way?
2. Is he doing it in a way that is equivalent to what I'm used to?
3. Can I / should I change his implementation because mine is more standard/readable?
4. Is what he is doing something more sophisticated (and therefore the answers are yes/no/no)?

Comment: you can read John Papa Angular style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md . Ofc it is just one opinion, but there are a lot of explanation of his style there.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the code will work fine.but not in the case of minification.

when you minify your JS,it also change the name of variable and make it smallest as possible.
example:

```
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    });
```

if you minify this code $scope will get changed to some other name which would be an unknown dependency for your controller hence this code will brake.

but if you write you code like this

```
 app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
        }]);
```

and minify this piece of code code will look something like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function(a){
            }]);
```

**it does not renamed `$scope` mentioned in single quotes because minifier understand it as a value. your controller replaces 'a' with '$scope' on execution i.e. you code will still be fine.**